# Highlight multiple PDFs in one folder

Tags: linux, find, filenames

I need to find every folder with more than one PDF in a folder structure but hide the pesky hidden files such as `.HResource` files that infiltrate our file system.

I only want to filter folders that have HiRes in the filename.

Ideally I want to run this at top level so it searches every folder with HiRes and spits out the folders with more than one PDF inside it.

The OS is RHEL 7 and this command can be run as user/root as required.

I have had a play with

```
find -type f -iname '*.pdf' -iname '*HiRes*' ! -iname '.*' -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -d
```

but have had very little luck so far as the hidden files keep showing and thus in a 11,000 folder system giving thousands of false positives. 
For example, given the following directory structure,

```
.
|--Apples.HiRes1
|     |--Gala.pdf
|     |--Granny Smith.pdf
|     |--McIntosh.pdf
|     |--Red Delicious.pdf
|--Banana-HiRes2
|     |--upper.pdf
|     |--subdir
|     |    |--lower.pdf
|--Cherry_HiRes3
|     |--Bing.pdf
|     |--Blossom.jpg
|     |--.pesky
|     |--.hidden
|     |--.files
|     |--.HResource
|--Dates (HiRes4)
|     |--Midsummer.Pdf
|     |--New Year’s Eve.PDF
|--Employees
|     |--Fred.pdf
|     |--Ginger.pdf
|     |--New Hires
|     |     |--Sam Malone.pdf
|     |     |--Woody Boyd.pdf
|--Gemstones
|     |--Rubies
|     |     |--1.pdf
|     |     |--2.pdf
|     |--Sapphires
|     |     |--3.pdf
|     |     |--4.pdf
|--Tomato.HiRes
|     |--Bacon
|     |--Lettuce
|     |     |--5.pdf
|     |     |--6.pdf
|--Zucchini.LoRes
|     |--Bread.pdf
|     |--Squash.pdf
```

the output should be

```
./Apples.HiRes1
./Dates (HiRes4)
```

Note that

- `Cherry_HiRes3` is excluded because it has only one PDF file in it.
- `Banana-HiRes2` and `Tomato.HiRes` are excluded
  because they have two PDF files *under* them, but not ***in*** them.
- `Zucchini.LoRes` is excluded (obviously)
  because its name has `LoRes` rather than `HiRes`.

Comment: (1) One of the primary rules of debugging is to break things into pieces.  Have you tried running your `find` command by itself, and looking at the output?  Is it what you expect?  Does that help you?  (2) Another debugging technique is to explain your problem to a rubber duck.  Can you explain how you *believe* your solution should work, and what output you expect to get from the `find` command?  (3) Do you have files with names like `.MRducks.pdf`?  If not, I don’t understand what issue you could possibly be having with “pesky hidden files” such as `.HResource`.  Can you explain?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: P.S. (4) I’ve taken the liberty of adding example data to your question.  Please verify that my edit makes sense.  In particular, would you want the “Banana” and “Tomato” directories to be listed?  (5) Do you really want the `*HiRes*` test to be case-insensitive?  Note that, if you do, “New hires” and “Sapphires” will be listed.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This actually doesn't work either. See the comments below.

---

Have you tried adding `-not -iname '.*'` to your `find` command? The `!` is probably not doing what you think it is.

This would result in `find -type f -iname '*.pdf' -iname 'HiRes' -not -iname '.*' -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -d`

Comment: In GNU `find`, `-not` and `!` mean the same thing.  In POSIX `find`, `-not` is not defined.  What do you think the `!` is doing in the OP’s command?  What do you think `-not` would do differently?  What do you think the OP thinks the `!` is doing in their command?

Comment: Given that it's on a Linux host (I know OP and know this to be true), I had issues with the same command on a test host. The `!` is handled by the shell (bash) as an event. I've previously had luck with `-not`, but apparently something has changed as you pointed out. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that’s close to what you tried is

```
find . -ipath '*HiRes*/*.pdf' -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -d
```

As you seem to (at least partially) understand,
the `-name` and `-iname` tests operate on only one ***filename***;
i.e., only one level of a pathname. 
So, when you say `-iname '*.pdf' -iname '*HiRes*'`,
that’s equivalent to `-iname '*HiRes*.pdf'`;
i.e., you’re looking for files whose names match both `*.pdf` and `*HiRes*`. 
However, the `-path`, `-ipath`, `-regex` and `-iregex` tests
operate on the entire path,
so this lists files whose pathname contains `HiRes` and ends with `.pdf`. 
We put a `/` between them
to make sure that the `HiRes` is in a directory names,
so we don’t find files called `abcHiRes123.pdf`.

We can do the exact same thing with

```
find . -iregex '.*HiRes.*/.*\.pdf' -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq –d
```

Note the difference between glob syntax (as used by `-ipath`)
and regex syntax. 
Dot (**`.`**) means any character,
so we need to use `.*` to match “anything”
and `\.` to match a literal **`.`**.

Both of the above will find the `Tomato.HiRes` directory
in the example in your question,
because  `.` matches `/`, so `.*/.*` matches `/Lettuce/5`,
so `.*HiRes.*/.*\.pdf` matches  `./Tomato.HiRes/Lettuce/5.pdf` . 
If that’s OK with you, great. 
But, if you want to count only the PDF files
that are ***in*** a `*HiRes` directory, use

```
find . -iregex '.*HiRes[^/]*/[^/]*\.pdf' -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -d
```

in which we use `[^/]` to match any character other than a `/`.

---

A substantially different approach, which may be easier to understand, is

```
find . -iname '*HiRes*' -type d -exec sh -c \
                    'shopt -s nocaseglob; for dir do files=("$dir"/*.pdf);
                    if [ "${#files[@]}" -gt 1 ]; then echo "$dir"; fi; done' sh {} +
```

This only uses `find` to find directories called `*HiRes*`. 
It then turns those directory names over to a short shell script,
which uses glob to enumerate all the PDF files in each directory
and count them.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Yeah, I tbought it was borderline, but I tbtally missed tbat typo.  The person who proposed that edit seems to be trying too hard (seemingly editing just for the sake of editing) and simultaneously not trying hard enough (missing low-hanging fruit).

Comment: In other news, I rejected [this suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/931341) for [this reason](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13646/354511 "‘‘Editing of recently closed questions’’ — It was a trivial edit to a question that had been closed less than five days."). Yeah; I should have written that as a custom close reason; I lost my keys.

Comment: Today’s edition: I voted to reject [this edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/935860) because it actually changed the answer.   (I subsequently [repaired the damage](https://superuser.com/posts/1506276/revisions).)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so I took another stab at this after realizing my previous answer was wrong. JandP, you are so close to having the right command.

---

**The Setup**

- 10 directories, 1-10, referred to as `$s` hereout
- `$n` files in each, where `$n` is the number of the directory, named `$s-$n.pdf`
- `$n` dotfiles in each, `.fake-$s-$n.pdf`

Command I used to create this tree of files:
`` for s in `seq 1 10`; do mkdir $s; cd $s; for n in `seq 1 $s`; do touch $s-$n.pdf; touch .fake-$s-$n.pdf; done; cd ..; done ``

Produced this tree:

```
.
├── 1
│   ├── 1-1.pdf
│   └── .fake-1-1.pdf
├── 10
│   ├── 10-10.pdf
│   ├── 10-1.pdf
│   ├── 10-2.pdf
│   ├── 10-3.pdf
│   ├── 10-4.pdf
│   ├── 10-5.pdf
│   ├── 10-6.pdf
│   ├── 10-7.pdf
│   ├── 10-8.pdf
│   ├── 10-9.pdf
│   ├── .fake-10-10.pdf
│   ├── .fake-10-1.pdf
│   ├── .fake-10-2.pdf
│   ├── .fake-10-3.pdf
│   ├── .fake-10-4.pdf
│   ├── .fake-10-5.pdf
│   ├── .fake-10-6.pdf
│   ├── .fake-10-7.pdf
│   ├── .fake-10-8.pdf
│   └── .fake-10-9.pdf
├── 2
│   ├── 2-1.pdf
│   ├── 2-2.pdf
│   ├── .fake-2-1.pdf
│   └── .fake-2-2.pdf
├── 3
│   ├── 3-1.pdf
│   ├── 3-2.pdf
│   ├── 3-3.pdf
│   ├── .fake-3-1.pdf
│   ├── .fake-3-2.pdf
│   └── .fake-3-3.pdf
├── 4
│   ├── 4-1.pdf
│   ├── 4-2.pdf
│   ├── 4-3.pdf
│   ├── 4-4.pdf
│   ├── .fake-4-1.pdf
│   ├── .fake-4-2.pdf
│   ├── .fake-4-3.pdf
│   └── .fake-4-4.pdf
├── 5
│   ├── 5-1.pdf
│   ├── 5-2.pdf
│   ├── 5-3.pdf
│   ├── 5-4.pdf
│   ├── 5-5.pdf
│   ├── .fake-5-1.pdf
│   ├── .fake-5-2.pdf
│   ├── .fake-5-3.pdf
│   ├── .fake-5-4.pdf
│   └── .fake-5-5.pdf
├── 6
│   ├── 6-1.pdf
│   ├── 6-2.pdf
│   ├── 6-3.pdf
│   ├── 6-4.pdf
│   ├── 6-5.pdf
│   ├── 6-6.pdf
│   ├── .fake-6-1.pdf
│   ├── .fake-6-2.pdf
│   ├── .fake-6-3.pdf
│   ├── .fake-6-4.pdf
│   ├── .fake-6-5.pdf
│   └── .fake-6-6.pdf
├── 7
│   ├── 7-1.pdf
│   ├── 7-2.pdf
│   ├── 7-3.pdf
│   ├── 7-4.pdf
│   ├── 7-5.pdf
│   ├── 7-6.pdf
│   ├── 7-7.pdf
│   ├── .fake-7-1.pdf
│   ├── .fake-7-2.pdf
│   ├── .fake-7-3.pdf
│   ├── .fake-7-4.pdf
│   ├── .fake-7-5.pdf
│   ├── .fake-7-6.pdf
│   └── .fake-7-7.pdf
├── 8
│   ├── 8-1.pdf
│   ├── 8-2.pdf
│   ├── 8-3.pdf
│   ├── 8-4.pdf
│   ├── 8-5.pdf
│   ├── 8-6.pdf
│   ├── 8-7.pdf
│   ├── 8-8.pdf
│   ├── .fake-8-1.pdf
│   ├── .fake-8-2.pdf
│   ├── .fake-8-3.pdf
│   ├── .fake-8-4.pdf
│   ├── .fake-8-5.pdf
│   ├── .fake-8-6.pdf
│   ├── .fake-8-7.pdf
│   └── .fake-8-8.pdf
└── 9
    ├── 9-1.pdf
    ├── 9-2.pdf
    ├── 9-3.pdf
    ├── 9-4.pdf
    ├── 9-5.pdf
    ├── 9-6.pdf
    ├── 9-7.pdf
    ├── 9-8.pdf
    ├── 9-9.pdf
    ├── .fake-9-1.pdf
    ├── .fake-9-2.pdf
    ├── .fake-9-3.pdf
    ├── .fake-9-4.pdf
    ├── .fake-9-5.pdf
    ├── .fake-9-6.pdf
    ├── .fake-9-7.pdf
    ├── .fake-9-8.pdf
    └── .fake-9-9.pdf

10 directories, 110 files
```

---

**The Lookup**

Using JandP's basic `find` command, and the knowledge revealed in the comments from my other (incorrect) answer, produced an output showing the number of matching files in each directory, *excluding* any dotfiles:

```
$ find -type f -iname '*.pdf' ! -iname '.*' -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c
      1 ./1
     10 ./10
      2 ./2
      3 ./3
      4 ./4
      5 ./5
      6 ./6
      7 ./7
      8 ./8
      9 ./9
```

Throwing a simple `awk` comparison on the end, produced the expected result:

```
$ find -type f -iname '*.pdf' ! -iname '.*' -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1'
     10 ./10
      2 ./2
      3 ./3
      4 ./4
      5 ./5
      6 ./6
      7 ./7
      8 ./8
      9 ./9
```

---

**The Conclusion**

JandP was oh so close. This answer took a little bit of Google-fu, but came together pretty easily from there. My recommendation is to study this scenario and answer, and apply it to your situation at hand. Then, pick it apart. Understand what each command does, why the arguments are stated the way they are, and what their produced output is. Learn why piping them together has the behavior it does. This will take you far in your career in systems administration.

Comment: I realize this doesn't fix the subdir issues. Perhaps a `-maxdepth ` argument to `find` would fix that.

Comment: “I only want to filter folders that have `HiRes` in the filename.”

Comment: Then change the first `-iname '*.pdf'` to include the appropriate pattern.